# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and the left endpoint of the interval.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Going through Stephen Abbot's Understanding Analysis he gave the following as the second statement of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:

> Let $g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be integrable and define
>   $$G(x)=\int _a^x g$$
>   for all $x\in[a,b]$. Then $G$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. If $g$ is continuous at some point $c\in[a,b]$, then $G$ is differentiable at $c$ and $G'(c)=g(c)$

Later in the exercises he asked:

> Let $$H(x)=\int _1^x \frac{1}{t}dt$$
>   For $x>0$.
>
> (a) What is $H(1)$? Find $H'(x)$.

Now as I see it, by the fundamental theorem for all $x\geq1$ we have $H'(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, but checking the answers Stephen Abbot claims that the fundamental theorem also implies that for $0<x<1$ $H'(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.

Any insight into why that is true? The fundamental theorem of calculus tells us that for $x\in[a,b]$ the derivative is the same, and it's obviously true for any $b>a$, but didn't we set $a=1$? How can we get lower values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: The value of $a$ is meaningless. It only adds a constant to the function $H$.

Comment: Well, that makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's a shame if this isn't explicitly spelled out in the book, but we do allow integrals from $a$ to $b$, where $b < a$, even though it makes little geometric sense. It is understood to mean the *negative* of the integral from $b$ to $a$. The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus holds not just for $x \ge a$, but for any $x$ such that the function is continuous between $x$ and $a$.

To see why, Przemysław Scherwentke has a good suggestion: just change $a$ to be something less than $x$. You'll create a new function that differs by a constant (in particular, the definite integral of the function between the two values of $a$), and hence has the same derivative.

Comment: He does mention that the value of $b$ can be negative, but that is mentioned as notation for the integral itself, and here in the definitions we have actual intervals where it makes no sense to have $b<a$ (or at least it wasn't defined)

Answer (score 1):

You can think of it this way. Let $x>0$. There exists $a>0$ such that $0<a<x$. Then we can rewrite $H$ as $H(x)=\displaystyle\int_a^x\frac{1}{t}dt-\displaystyle\int_ a^1\frac{1}{t}dt$. Since the second term is just a constant, it becomes zero after getting differentiated. The first term, you can apply the Theorem and get $H'(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ for $x>0$.